# How to compute the inverse of a close to singular matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, inverse, singular

I want to minimize function FlogV (working with a multinormal distribution, Z is data matrix NxC; SIGMA it´s a square matrix CxC of var-covariance of data, R a vector with length C)

```
FLogV <- function(P){

(here I define parameters, P, within R and SIGMA)

logC <- (C/2)*N*log(2*pi)+(1/2)*N*log(det(SIGMA))

SOMA.t <- 0

for (j in 1:N){
SOMA.t <- SOMA.t+sum(t(Z[j,]-R)%*%solve(SIGMA)%*%(Z[j,]-R))
}

MlogV <- logC + (1/2)*SOMA.t

return(MlogV)

}

minLogV <- optim(P,FLogV)
```

All this is part of an extend code which was already tested and works well, except in the most important thing: I can´t optimize because I get this error:
“Error in solve.default(SIGMA) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.57726e-55”

If I use ginv() or pseudoinverse() or qr.solve() I get:
“Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'”

The thing is: if I take the SIGMA matrix after the error message, I can solve(SIGMA), the eigen values are all positive and the determinant is very small but positive
    det(SIGMA)
    [1] 3.384674e-76

```
eigen(SIGMA)$values
[1] 0.066490265 0.024034173 0.018738777 0.015718562 0.013568884 0.013086845
….
[31] 0.002414433 0.002061556 0.001795105 0.001607811
```

I already read several papers about change matrices like SIGMA (which are close to singular), did several transformations on data scale and form but I realized that, for a 34x34 matrix like the example, after det(SIGMA) close to e-40, R assumes it like 0 and calculation fails; also I can´t reduce matrix dimensions and can´t input in my function correction algorithms to singular matrices because R can´t evaluate it working with this optimization functions like optim. I really appreciate any suggestion to this problem.
Thanks in advance, 
Maria D.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear from your post whether the failure is coming from `det()` or `solve()`

If its just the solve in the quadratic term, you may want to try the two argument version of `solve`, it can be a bit more stable. `solve(X,Y)` is the same as `solve(X) %*% Y`

If you can factor sigma using `chol()`, you will get a triangular matrix such that LL'=Sigma. The determinant is the product of the diagonals, and you might try this for the quadratic term:

```
crossprod( backsolve(L, Z[j,]-R))
```